# How to prevent / remove duplicate modules and mismatched version numbers (i.e. @polkdadot/types)?

Tags: polkadot-js, typescript

I am still learning TypeScript and I have some code that is working, but it returns a lot of messages about multiple versions of modules and conflicting packages.  What is the best way to fix these messages?  Also, based on my readings yarn supposedly automatically dedupes when you use `yarn add`, but that is not my experience based on these messages.  I know the package.json lists the dependencies and version numbers, but I don't know enough to know how to modify that file to fix this problem.  Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

```
@polkadot/util has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 9.1.1       node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/util/cjs
        cjs 9.1.1       node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/util/cjs
@polkadot/util-crypto has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 9.1.1       node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/util-crypto/cjs
        cjs 9.1.1       node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/util-crypto/cjs
@polkadot/wasm-crypto has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 6.0.1       node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/wasm-crypto/cjs
        cjs 6.0.1       node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/wasm-crypto/cjs
@polkadot/wasm-crypto-wasm has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 6.0.1       node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/wasm-crypto-wasm/cjs
        cjs 6.0.1       node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/wasm-crypto-wasm/cjs
@polkadot/util has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 9.1.1       node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/util/cjs
        cjs 9.1.1       node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/util/cjs
        cjs 9.1.1       node_modules/@polkadot/types-known/node_modules/@polkadot/util/cjs
@polkadot/types-create has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.3.1       node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/types-create/cjs
        cjs 8.3.1       node_modules/@polkadot/types-known/node_modules/@polkadot/types-create/cjs
@polkadot/types-codec has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.3.1       node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/types-codec/cjs
        cjs 8.3.1       node_modules/@polkadot/types-known/node_modules/@polkadot/types-codec/cjs
@polkadot/util has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 9.1.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/util/cjs
        cjs 9.1.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/util/cjs
        cjs 9.1.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/types-known/node_modules/@polkadot/util/cjs
        cjs 8.7.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/util
@polkadot/rpc-core has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.3.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-core/cjs
        cjs 7.15.1      /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-core
@polkadot/types has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.3.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/types/cjs
        cjs 7.15.1      /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-core/node_modules/@polkadot/types
@polkadot/types-create has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.3.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/types-create/cjs
        cjs 8.3.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/types-known/node_modules/@polkadot/types-create/cjs
        cjs 7.15.1      /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/types-create
@polkadot/types-codec has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.3.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/types-codec/cjs
        cjs 8.3.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/types-known/node_modules/@polkadot/types-codec/cjs
        cjs 7.15.1      /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/types-codec
@polkadot/util-crypto has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 9.1.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/util-crypto/cjs
        cjs 9.1.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/util-crypto/cjs
        cjs 8.7.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/util-crypto
@polkadot/wasm-crypto has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 6.0.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/wasm-crypto/cjs
        cjs 6.0.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/wasm-crypto/cjs
        cjs 5.1.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/wasm-crypto
@polkadot/wasm-crypto-wasm has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 6.0.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/api/node_modules/@polkadot/wasm-crypto-wasm/cjs
        cjs 6.0.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/types/node_modules/@polkadot/wasm-crypto-wasm/cjs
        cjs 5.1.1       /Users/rogerbos/subquery/pulse/node_modules/@polkadot/wasm-crypto-wasm
karura
```

Comment: As the message suggests, run `yarn dedupe` or `npm dedupe` (depending on your package manager)

Comment: Does `yarn dedupe` actually work for other people?  when I try it I get an error message that it isn't necessary (and it doesn't do anything): ```rogerbos@rogers-mbp pulse % yarn dedupe
yarn dedupe v1.22.18
warning ../../package.json: No license field
error The dedupe command isn't necessary. `yarn install` will already dedupe.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/dedupe for documentation about this command.```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your **polkadot** resolutions to the same values as [polkadot apps](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/master/package.json) and you should be good to go. This is what they're currently set to:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "@polkadot/api": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/api-augment": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/api-base": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/api-contract": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/api-derive": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/hw-ledger": "^9.1.1",
    "@polkadot/keyring": "^9.1.1",
    "@polkadot/networks": "^9.1.1",
    "@polkadot/phishing": "^0.12.1",
    "@polkadot/rpc-augment": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/rpc-core": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/rpc-provider": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/types": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/types-augment": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/types-codec": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/types-create": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/types-known": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/types-support": "^8.3.1",
    "@polkadot/util": "^9.1.1",
    "@polkadot/util-crypto": "^9.1.1",
    "@polkadot/wasm-crypto": "^6.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
```

If you still hit issues after this, try removing the hats (`^`) from the resolutions to force a specific version. The `^` indicates that you are willing to take further increments but not move to a new major version

> ^1.2.3 will match any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but will hold off on 2.0.0

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565344/in-package-json-dependency-version#22565385)

Comment: Great suggestion.  I didn't want to mess with the resolutions myself because I don't know which version to use, but the suggestion to get them from Polkadot was helpful.  Note that I had to delete the node_modules and re-install to resolve other errors.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The message does suggest `npm dedupe` or `yarn dedupe`. In my experience the package managers don't apply it consistently, especially when upgrading.

There does seem to be an issue with your deps however, some seem to require 9.1.1 and other 8.7.1 of the util dependencies.

In the worst-case, when using yarn, you can always resort to `resolutions`, but that would assume that you really have the latest of all required. (Which as per the point above doesn't seem to be the case here)